# Error while running ClassSpy java

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to execute the oracle classspy.java in netbeans and also in terminal but i am getting error

```
Could not find or load main class ClassSpy.java
```

Here is the source code

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import static java.lang.System.out;

enum ClassMember { CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, METHOD, CLASS, ALL }

public class ClassSpy {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
        out.format("Class:%n  %s%n%n", c.getCanonicalName());

        Package p = c.getPackage();
        out.format("Package:%n  %s%n%n",
               (p != null ? p.getName() : "-- No Package --"));

        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        switch (ClassMember.valueOf(args[i])) {
        case CONSTRUCTOR:
            printMembers(c.getConstructors(), "Constructor");
            break;
        case FIELD:
            printMembers(c.getFields(), "Fields");
            break;
        case METHOD:
            printMembers(c.getMethods(), "Methods");
            break;
        case CLASS:
            printClasses(c);
            break;
        case ALL:
            printMembers(c.getConstructors(), "Constuctors");
            printMembers(c.getFields(), "Fields");
            printMembers(c.getMethods(), "Methods");
            printClasses(c);
            break;
        default:
            assert false;
        }
        }

        // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private static void printMembers(Member[] mbrs, String s) {
    out.format("%s:%n", s);
    for (Member mbr : mbrs) {
        if (mbr instanceof Field)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Field)mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Constructor)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Constructor)mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Method)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Method)mbr).toGenericString());
    }
    if (mbrs.length == 0)
        out.format("  -- No %s --%n", s);
    out.format("%n");
    }

    private static void printClasses(Class<?> c) {
    out.format("Classes:%n");
    Class<?>[] clss = c.getClasses();
    for (Class<?> cls : clss)
        out.format("  %s%n", cls.getCanonicalName());
    if (clss.length == 0)
        out.format("  -- No member interfaces, classes, or enums --%n");
    out.format("%n");
    }
}
```

Help needed to run this code i am getting same error in netbeans too and also in cmd.

Comment: Don't run it as `java ClassSpy.java` but as `java ClassSpy`. And ofcourse you first have to compile your program before you run it.

Answer (score 0):

For terminal first compile using

```
javac ClassSpy.java
```

followed by `java ClassSpy` for execution.
For further options on javac refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html